# Enable C++ compiler warning for missing XML documentation

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010, documentation, compiler-warnings

When XML documentation is enabled for my C++ projects (managed) the compiler does not raise any warnings for missing comments.

I have enabled the documentation generation by setting "Generate XML documentation Files" (/doc) to true as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173501.aspx). The project is configured as a dynamic library with /clr and warning level 4 (/W4).

For C# projects the compiler raises a [Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'Type_or_Member'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk18c1w9.aspx) warning when comments are missing. To force the developers to make the appropriate comments I would like to have the same behavior for the C++ projects. How do I obtain that?

Comment: I don't believe there's an option for that in C++ projects. The XML documentation support for C# is much "richer" by comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VC++ XML comments are not processed the say way as for .NET. The VC++ compiler processes the comments and generates .xdc files which are later assembled by a tool called xdcmake.exe into xml files. However, there is no option to tell the compiler to issue warnings if XML comments as known to .NET are missing.

(See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177227.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177247.aspx)

Comment: Do you know of any alternative ways to perform this check? Any tools?

Comment: No, I don't know. I don't write XML comments in VC++. But there might be some tools to do that. You might want to check the Visual Studio Gallery for that.